# Automatically close Workbook after inactivity

Tags: vba, excel

I created a Macro that closes the WB after some time of inactivity. It works perfect if I manually open the file, but if I use another macro from a different WB to open the file, it won't close automatically after the set inactivity time. The code I used to automatically close it is:

This Workbook module:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    stop_Countdown
ThisWorkbook.Save
End Sub
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    start_Countdown
    End Sub
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    stop_Countdown
    start_Countdown
    End Sub
Private Sub Workbook_SheetCalculate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    stop_Countdown
    start_Countdown
End Sub
Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, _
  ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    stop_Countdown
    start_Countdown
End Sub
```

Regular Module:

```
Option Explicit
Public Close_Time As Date
Sub start_Countdown()
    Close_Time = Now() + TimeValue("00:00:10")
    Application.OnTime Close_Time, "close_WB"
    End Sub
Sub stop_Countdown()
    Application.OnTime Close_Time, "close_WB", , False
    End Sub
Sub close_wb()
    ThisWorkbook.Close True
    End Sub
```

The code of the other macro:

```
Sub Answer_Quote()

Worksheets("UI RM").Protect DrawingObjects:=False, Contents:=False, Scenarios:=False, Password:="045"

 Dim wBook As Workbook
    On Error Resume Next
    Set wBook = Workbooks("Base de Datos Cotizaciones Shared.xlsb")

    If wBook Is Nothing Then 'Not open
            Set wBook = Nothing
            On Error GoTo 0
    Else 'It is open
            wBook.Close SaveChanges:=False
            Set wBook = Nothing
            On Error GoTo 0
    End If

Set wb4 = ActiveWorkbook
Range("AM7").Calculate
Range("K26:K28").Calculate
Dim arreglo(4) As Variant
arreglo(0) = Range("hour_sent").Value
arreglo(1) = Range("day_sent").Value
arreglo(2) = Range("respuesta").Value
arreglo(3) = Range("UsernameRM").Value

Dim Findwhat As String
Dim c, d, multirange As Range
Findwhat = Range("F11").Text

    Dim contador As Integer
    contador = 0
    While (IsFileOpen("\\3kusmiafs02\CARPETA COMERCIAL\Cotizaciones\Base de Datos Cotizaciones Shared.xlsb") And contador < 4)
        contador = contador + 1
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:03"))
    Wend

    If contador = 4 Then
    MsgBox "La base de datos esta siendo utilizada por otro usuario. Por favor vuelva a intentarlo", vbExclamation, "Proceso cancelado"
    Exit Sub
    End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim iStatus As Long
Err.Clear
On Error Resume Next
Set wb2 = Workbooks("Base de Datos Cotizaciones Shared.xlsb")
iStatus = Err
On Error GoTo 0
If iStatus Then 'workbook isn't open
Workbooks.Open filename:="\\3kusmiafs02\CARPETA COMERCIAL\Cotizaciones\Base de Datos Cotizaciones Shared.xlsb"
Else
'workbook is open
wb2.Activate
End If

On Error GoTo errHandler:

'Copy Hour Sent
Worksheets("Data").Activate
Set c = Range("A:A").Find(Findwhat, LookIn:=xlValues)
For j = 1 To 3
    c.Offset(0, 17 + j) = arreglo(j - 1)
Next j
c.Offset(0, 29) = arreglo(3)


'Save Database
Workbooks("Base de Datos Cotizaciones Shared.xlsb").Save
Workbooks("Base de Datos Cotizaciones Shared.xlsb").Close

    'Step-Back into User Interface
    wb4.Activate
    Worksheets("UI RM").Activate

    'Send E-Mail

    'Working in 2000-2010
    Dim Source As Range
    Dim Dest As Workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim TempFilePath As String
    Dim TempFileName As String
    Dim FileExtStr As String
    Dim FileFormatNum As Long
    Dim response As Variant


    'Mail recipients

     Dim mail_recipients(3) As String

     'mail_recipients(1) = Range("email").Value
     'mail_recipients(2) = "mail"
     mail_recipients(3) = "mail2"


    'Source Set/Range selection

     Set Source = Nothing
     On Error Resume Next

    Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets("Interline Costs")).Name = "Quote Snap"

    'copy temp info
    Worksheets("UI RM").Activate
    Range("B7:G31").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Worksheets("quote snap").Activate
    Range("b2").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    ActiveSheet.Paste

    'copy temp dims
    Worksheets("UI rm").Activate
    Range("I21:s33").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
        Selection.Copy
    Worksheets("Quote Snap").Activate
    Range("H3").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Columns("j:j").Select
    Selection.ColumnWidth = 12

    'select temp sheet
    Range("A1:V600").Select


Set Source = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)


    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set Dest = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)

    Source.Copy
    With Dest.Sheets(1)
        .Cells.Interior.Pattern = xlSolid
        .Cells.Interior.PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Cells.Interior.ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
        .Cells.Interior.TintAndShade = 0
        .Cells.Interior.PatternTintAndShade = 0
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False

    End With

    TempFilePath = Environ$("temp") & "\"
    TempFileName = "Response to Quote #" & wb4.Worksheets("UI RM").Range("F11")

    If Val(Application.Version) < 12 Then
        'You use Excel 2000-2003
        FileExtStr = ".xls": FileFormatNum = -4143
    Else
        'You use Excel 2007-2010
        FileExtStr = ".xlsx": FileFormatNum = 51
    End If
    With Dest
        .SaveAs TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr, _
                FileFormat:=FileFormatNum
        On Error Resume Next
        For i = 1 To 3
            .SendMail Recipients:=mail_recipients, _
                     Subject:="Response to Quote #" & wb4.Worksheets("UI RM").Range("quote_num") & " " & wb4.Worksheets("UI RM").Range("client") & " " & wb4.Worksheets("UI RM").Range("destination") & " " & wb4.Worksheets("UI RM").Range("total_KGS") & " KGS"

            If Err.Number = 0 Then Exit For
        Next i
        On Error GoTo 0
        .Close SaveChanges:=False
    End With

    'Delete the file you have send
    Kill TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    wb4.Worksheets("quote snap").Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True


MsgBox "Proceso Terminado"

wb4.Sheets("UI RM").Range("limpiar").ClearContents
wb4.Sheets("UI RM").Range("F29").ClearContents
wb4.Sheets("UI RM").Range("E43:I80").ClearContents

    'Starting Point
    wb4.Worksheets("UI RM").Activate
    Range("F11").Select

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Worksheets("UI RM").Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True, Password:="045"


Exit Sub

errHandler:

Dim wBook1 As Workbook
    On Error Resume Next
    Set wBook1 = Workbooks("Base de Datos Cotizaciones Shared.xlsb")

    If wBook1 Is Nothing Then 'Not open
            Set wBook1 = Nothing
            On Error GoTo 0
    Else 'It is open
            wBook1.Close SaveChanges:=False
            Set wBook1 = Nothing
            On Error GoTo 0
    End If
MsgBox "Hubo un error", vbExclamation, "Error"

End Sub
```

Any ideas?

Comment: does the other macro disable events `(Application.EnableEvents = False)` before it opens this Workbook?

Comment: no, it doesn't, unless that's the default setting...

Comment: Please share the code from the other macro that opens this file.

Comment: I just added it to the question

Comment: Your other code doesn't appear to trigger any of the events in that workbook that would start the timer...

Comment: so, what should I add to the other code?

Comment: @MacroMan - `Workbook_Open` event get *at least* should be triggered and start the countdown.

Comment: @N.Pavon - if you step through the code line-by-line, does the `Workbook_Open` event fire in the workbook with the timer code in it when opened from the other sub?

Comment: @ScottHoltzman I didn't see the `Workbooks.Open()` method - didn't scroll down!

Comment: @ScottHoltzman yes, it does fire... but after some more lines of code, the stop_countdown() procedure throws this error:

Comment: Can't execute code in break mode

Comment: Is your network path a **Trusted Location** in the Excel **Sercurity Settings**? Otherwise it won't run macros in those files.

Comment: @SvenRojek where do I check the security settings?

Comment: @SvenRojek - if the `Workbook_Open` event is firing, then it's not an issue with `Trusted Location`.

Comment: @N.Pavon - See the 2 links in the comments to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19624411/excel-2010-vba-throws-cant-execute-code-in-break-mode-while-stepping). Of particular interest, will be the 2nd link. You may be very well served here in cleaning up your code and removing all `ActiveSheet` and `Select` statements. These can be hazardous to a VBA developer's health :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I know those statements are "hazardous", but I didn't develop this code, I'm only mending it. I was expecting that comment haha. By the way, why is it frowned upon?

Comment: I think I know what the problem was. When the WB opens the WB that should close after inactivity, macros are not enabled. How do I tell the first WB to enable the macros of the opening WB right after opening it?

Comment: @ScottHoltzman I wasn't aware of that, are you sure?
@N.Pavon You'll find it here:
`File -> Options -> Trust Center -> Trust Center Settings -> Trusted Locations` and add your network location. Also check `Allow Trusted Locations on my network`.

Comment: @SvenRojek - It depends on the settings, but if Excel did not trust the document the code would not fire when the Workbook is opened. A prompt would appear to either `Enable Content` or `Enable Macros` or a warning that `Macros are Disabled` and *nothing* would happen in terms of code execution.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman That's totally true if he opens the file at the same location manually.

Comment: re: *but after some more lines of code, the stop_countdown() procedure throws this error*  .. What error?

Comment: I have tried *auto-close* code and it works even workbook opened from VBA..so the issue must be something else..

Answer (score 1):

As Susilo pointed out in the comments, the issue must be something else than the auto-close code itself, since it works. That "something else" then, is probably the `Answer_Quote()` code, which frankly is one big mess. I'd recommend the following:

**USE DUMMY CODE**

Try running a dummy macro (a macro that essentially does nothing but open the workbook that should auto-close after some inactivity) instead of `Answer_Quote()`to see if the problem persists. If it doesn't, then you know for sure that `Answer_Quote()` is causing the problem. Proceed then to code cleanup.

**CODE CLEANUP**

1) Set all objects, external file and sheet references to nothing upon exit.

Optionally and thus less importantly, but to ease code maintenance and debugging, I'd also recommend:

2) Use proper and consistent indentation

3) Remove redundant lines of code

For instance:

```
If wBook Is Nothing Then 'Not open
        Set wBook = Nothing
```

It is obviously pointless to set a reference to nothing if it is already nothing.

4) Dimension all variables at the top, rather than throughout the code.

5) Use `Option explicit` (if you don't already)

**TEST AUTO-CLOSE EXECUTION**

After code cleanup, test again. If the problem persists, try commenting out some of the`Answer_Quote()` code and try again. Repeat this process until the auto-close execution works again and you can pinpoint the exact cause of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

try adding  a stop statement to your workbook_open to test if the event is even being triggered

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
  start_Countdown
  Stop
End Sub
```

this would be a brute force way the to run the open Event from the Calling Workbook.

`Application.Run(ActiveWorkbook.name & "!Workbook_Open")`

add this just after you open the Workbook.